# Are vpns all compatible with each other? Can openvpn be substituted for Cisco Anyconnect?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My university uses Cisco anyconnect and Duo to authenticate.
When logging into the vpn, I have to run anyconnect, connect to the vpn server, and type in:

userid
password
and a second factor 6-digit code from Duo.

The whole process is slow and annoying. Is there anything I can do to turn this into a command line operation? Can I use any open source vpn, is there a way to record my password and to get authentication at least to just be clicking yes on the duo app?

Comment: I don't know much about vpns, but asking whether they are compatible is a networking question. It seems just as relevant to me as if I ask about ssh

Comment: "auserid password and a second factor 6-digit code from Duo."   You can put it in a 1 char bash script IF the code is the same each time. Othewise a 1 char named scropt with the code as an argument (would make it either ./a or ./a 123456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.
There are several incompatible VPN protocols in the field.
Most notably, IPsec and SSL-VPN (the two protocols supported by Cisco AnyConnect) are both mutually incompatible with the OpenVPN protocol.

You may however be able to streamline the process by running the Cisco AnyConnect command line client, typically `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn`, with appropriate arguments. Run

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -h
```

for details.

Comment: Should mention OpenConnect - which is a Cisco Anyconnect compatible implementation which in many cases works better than Ciscos software...